# What happens if you buy a elixir pack the get raided?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Do I lose most of it? I’m th 5 and I bought 2.5 million of elixir and gold do i lose half of it or all of it?

Comment: I can’t spend the elixir because I maxed out everything with elixer

Comment: I cant say 100% for sure but I imagine its treated as any other resource. Ive never bought resources though, but I dont see why they would protect what you bought over what was gathered.

Answer (score 1):

The amount you lose depends on your town hall level. The maximum you could lose is 20% if you are level 6 or lower.

[image]

Found here: https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Raids#Loot